# @SuppressLint("CheckResult") doesn't seem to work

Tags: android-studio, lint, suppress-warnings

This method

```
@SuppressLint("CheckResult")
public int update(String columnName, long value) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(columnName, value);
    return update(cv);
}
```

wraps the `update` method of an `SQLdatabase`. Since the wrapped method returns a value, the wrapper should return a value as well, and it does so. However as it happens my existing code doesn't yet use the returned value since I don't usually want to know how many rows got updated, so Android Studio's lint checker complains with a CheckResult error. I expect the `SuppressLint` call to stop it complaining, but it still complains. How do I suppress the warning? Disabling CheckResult globally might work, but this would mean that I don't get the warning in other places where I might want it.

Suppressing warnings in Android Studio seems a bit hit-and-miss. For some warnings
`@SuppressLint("<tag>")`
will work. For some others
`@SuppressWarnings("<tag>")`
will work. For yet others
`//noinspection <tag>`
(no quotes) will work. None of them works in this particular case.
<flame>
This really isn't very coder-friendly. At the very least the designers could usefully publish a list of which annotation works for each warning. As a software designer, I *don't care* which part of the Android Studio code inspection generated the warning, and as a software designer with 50 years of experience I would *never* have designed a user interface like that.
</flame>

Answer (score 0):

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedReturnValue")

works. I'm not quite sure why I expected the tag to be "CheckResult". Presumably this appeared in the warning message at the time.